# Picking 8 characters

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

We have 5 characters. We want to pick 8 of them (order matters and duplicates are allowed, obviously) but we must pick every character at least 1 time.

How many ways are there to pick those 8 characters?

Comment: Hint:  once you've chosen one each of the five, there are only three choices left to make.  Those possibilities are pretty easy to enumerate.

Comment: Actually...what do you mean "order matters"?  If the characters are $\{A,B,C,D,E\}$ is $ABCDEAAA$ different from $AAAABCDE$?

Comment: @lulu yes, that's exacty what I mean

Comment: So they are different?  Ok, that complicates things slightly.   For each possible pattern you will have to multiply by the number of permutations of that pattern and different patterns may not have the same number of permutations (as $AAAABCDE$ has $\frac {8!}{4!}$ permutations but $AAABBCDE$ has $\frac {8!}{3!\times 2!}$ permutations).  Still not too bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the characters be $S = \{A,B,C,D,E\}$. Let $X_i$ be the set of 8-strings that does NOT contain the character $i$. Then the union
$$X_A\cup X_B\cup X_C\cup X_D\cup X_E = \bigcup_{i\in S} X_i$$
is the set of 8-strings that does NOT satisfy your requirement. The number of elements $\left|\bigcup_{i\in S} X_i\right|$ can be found by inclusion-exclusion principle, which is

- the number of strings missing one character, counted once for each missing character: $5\cdot4^8 = 327680$
- minus those missing two characters, counted once for each pair of missing character: $-\binom{5}{2}\cdot3^8 = -65610$
- plus those missing three characters, counted once for each triplet of missing characters: $\binom53\cdot2^8 = 2560$
- minus those missing four characters, counted once for each set of 4 missing characters: $-\binom54\cdot1^8 = -5$
- plus those missing all 5 characters: $0$

The sum of these 5 terms is $264625$. Since the number of all 8-strings is $5^8 = 390625$, the required answer is
$$5^8 - \binom51 4^8 + \binom52 3^8-\binom53 2^8+\binom54 1^8 - 0 = 126000$$

Comment: If instead of 5 characters I had 3, what the answer would be, please?

Answer (score 4):

We can think of this problem as two steps.

Step 1: choose each of the five

Step2: Choose the rest three.

There are three cases in step two, can each will result different result.

- Case 1: Choose the same letter three times.

$5\choose 1$ ways to choose that letter. Then you would have 4 same letter in total. And that gives you ${5\choose 1}\frac{8!}{4!}$ different orders.

- Case 2: Choose the same letter twice, and choose another letter.

${5\choose2}$ ways to choose the two letters. Then you would have ${5\choose 2}\frac{8!}{3!2!}$ different orders.

- Case 3: Choose three different letters.

${5\choose3}$ ways to choose the three letters. Then you would have ${5\choose 3}\frac{8!}{2!2!2!}$ different orders.

So in total, you would have ${5\choose 1}\frac{8!}{4!}+{5\choose 2}\frac{8!}{3!2!}+{5\choose 3}\frac{8!}{2!2!2!}=92400$ different choices.

Hope that helps!

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you undercounted those in case 2, because the two letters chosen do not have the same role.

Comment: This is incorrect.  In case #2 there are $5$ ways to choose the "double" and then $4$ ways to choose the singleton.  That's $5\times 4 = 20$ ways in total.   If you make that change then your answer (which looks good otherwise) will match the answer supplied by @peterwhy